# python using search engine to find text in text file

Tags: python, search-engine

I have lots of text files in a directory.Then i will ask a keyword from the user.If the user enters for eg: 'hello'
Then,it has to search the entire text file of all the directories present in the text file and then search and return the line of the text file ,having the high priority of word hello.

Eg:

```
input: helloworld
```

output:

```
filename: abcd.txt
line : this world is a good world saying hello
```

Give me some ideas on how to deal with such problems!

Comment: Delegate to `grep`, will be faster than anything you do in Python.

Comment: Depending on how many files you have, how large they are, and so forth, you might want to look into Whoosh, a full text indexing package written in pure Python

Comment: @Amadan could you explain a little or provide me some link?

Comment: @duhaime yeah i heard off,but i didnot see an example relating my question over the net.Could you provide me some link?

Comment: Sure thing! Here are the docs:http://pythonhosted.org//Whoosh/quickstart.html That sai, @Amadan's response should get you there so long as you're not dealing with a tremendous amount of data.

Comment: @duhaime: It is the fastest you can get on non-indexed data, as long as you pay attention to proper regexp/shell escaping (which is pain in the behind). If you have a tremendous amount of data, you can still do it by using `Popen` the long way (with pipes) instead of the `check_output` shortcut. That said, any approach that indexes the data instead of doing raw search will be faster than the hack what I wrote. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using glob as alternative, you can filter for specific file name, extension or all file in directory.

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> key = 'hello'
>>> for file in glob("e:\data\*.txt"):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        line_no = 0
        for lines in f:
            line_no+=1
            if key.lower() in lines.lower():
                print "Found in " + file + "(" + str(line_no) + "): " + lines.rstrip()

Found in e:\data\data1.txt(1): Hello how are you
Found in e:\data\data2.txt(4): Searching for hello
Found in e:\data\data2.txt(6): 3 hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/env", "grep", "-nHr", "hello", "."])
matches = (line.split(":", 2) for line in output.split("\n") if line != "")
for [file, line, text] in matches:
    ....
```

This will find all mentions of "hello" in current directory or below. `man grep` for details on options. Be aware you will need to quote any special characters; if you're looking for simple words, this is not necessary, but if you're handling user input, you need to care about it.